# how to construct json object using any json library/jar

Tags: java, json

I just want to construct JSON object something like this:

```
"Root":{
  "c1": "v1"
}
```

I tried with the following code :

```
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;


public class Exe {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject("ROOT");
        object.put("c1", "v1");
        System.out.println(object.toString());
    }
}
```

with this code, I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of ROOT
```

I played with codehaus API, but I didn't find the solution, so can you please help me on this.

Comment: You can use [json.org -> for java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library. Its simple and usefull. You can create json object with same syntax in javascript.
Example : 
String jsonStr = "{myKey1:'myValue1'}";
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonStr );

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the JSONObject and then add the `"Root": value` key-value pair to the object.  The constructor accepting a String where you have `"Root"` expects a complete JSON object as a String.

```
JSONObject requestedObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject innerValue = new JSONObject();
innerValue.put("c1", "v1");
requestedObject.put("Root", innerValue);
System.out.println(requestedObject);
```

has been confirmed to produce:

```
{"Root":{"c1":"v1"}}
```

As an important additional note, the JSON object you request isn't a valid JSON object.  In case you're interested, you can check for valid JSON with a [JSON lint tool](https://jsonlint.com/).  A valid object is shown below.

```
{
    "Root":{
        "c1": "v1"
    }
}
```

Here's a quick snippet to confirm the statement about the constructor with a String.

```
JSONObject strConstr = new JSONObject("{\"Root\":{\"c1\":\"v1\"}}");
System.out.println(strConstr);
```

has been confirmed to produce:

```
{"Root":{"c1":"v1"}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I'll try this

Comment: No problem @Creator!  I'm glad I can help.